# White-space right hand side of the page

Tags: css, wordpress

I uploaded the WordPress few days ago and found out that the one on local host and the one on the website **www.noteid.com** are different.

The one on the website has the white-space on the right hand side:

[image]

[image]

So I did test it with my theme and the one that WP has: Twenty-Fourteen

All the others theme work fine but two of those.

It seem like: `html { overflow-x: hidden }` work but I want to find what cause the problem. I took 2 days do the research and feel like nothing work out.

Can anyone help me to point out what happening to my website?

Thank in advance.

This is CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/n9zqygcj/

Comment: You need to provide the CSS/HTML code or a link or a JS Fiddle. Otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I checked the following link out of curiosity and everything seems fine: http://noteid.com/?page_id=7 I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: try my solution below, that'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that the `#footer` width is 105% of the page.
You need to change:

```
#footer {
    padding-left:0;
}
#colophon {
    margin-left:5%
}
```

So that the footer isn't longer than it should be.

EDIT:

Here is the updated CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/n9zqygcj/2/

Answer (score 1):

The `<a>` tag which is wrapped around the `<div id="footer">` should be assigned a `class`, for e.g. `<a href="#" class="footerlink">` and then the following styles should be added to inside your stylesheet:

```
.footerlink {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Apart from this, also add the following style to your stylesheet:

```
.metaslider {
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hopefully this will eliminate the problem of extra white space on the right side which you're facing on your website.

Comment: I read it carefully and replaced the code - It seem like the problem is the slider and footer that i have. The `overflow: hidden;` wont work and still breaks the site.